# android - rendering bitmaps from native code - nativeCreate bitmaps are not cleanedup from memory

Tags: android, crash, bitmap, android-emulator, android-ndk

I am streaming a video in android and I decode frames in native code and then copy the pixels to a bitmap, then display the bitmap in Java using canvas.unlockandpost with a while loop for all the bitmaps.

Everything is fine, but the streaming of bitmaps is very slow and causes a crash. I only see a message on logcat saying that "low memory no more background processes".

I see on the allocation table from eclipse, that the bitmaps that I created are not getting deleted from memory, even though, I am overwritng the pixels everytime. Is there any way I can clean up the memory it is keeping.

My code is as follows.

C Code :

```
AndroidBitmapInfo  info;
void*              pixels;
int                ret;


if ((ret =AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels)) < 0) {
}

memcpy(pixels, pictureRGB, 480*320);

AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
```

Java Code

```
     Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 320, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
     renderbitmap(mBitmap, 0);
     canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown in your question is missing some critical parts to fully understand your problem, but it sounds like you're creating a new bitmap for every frame.  Since Android only allows for about 16MB of allocations for each Java VM, your app will get killed after about 52 frames.  You can create a bitmap once and re-use it many times.  To be more precise, you are creating a bitmap (Bitmap.CreateBitmap), but not destroying it (Bitmap.recycle).  That would solve your memory leak, but still would not be the best way to handle it.  Since the bitmap size doesn't change, create it once when your activity starts and re-use it throughout the life of your activity.